# I am unable to install emmet plugin on windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-emmet-vim

My directory structure is as follows

```
Vim/ 
-vim74/
   -autoload/
   -emmet-vim-master/
      -autoload
          -emmet/
      -plugin
      -doc
  -plugin/
  -color/
  -ftplugin/
-vimfiles/
  -autoload/
      -vim-pathogen-master
  -bundle/
      -vim-kolor-master/
      -emmet-vim-master/

  -plugin
-_vimrc
-_vimrc~
```

I am trying to install vim plugin but can't. Where am I missing ?

Comment: It's looking like you are trying install plugin via pathogen, but you don't have one. Does other 3rd party plugins work for you?

Comment: None of the plugins work....what is the problem

Comment: I'd recommend you to reinstall vim, because your file hierarchy kind of messy maybe something went wrong when you tried to solve this issue. After reinstaling vim install pathogen plugin, and after it just put emmet in the pathogen's bundle directory. It should work.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the fact that Vim's default runtime files and directories are off limits.

Put your plugins in:

```
%userprofile%\vimfiles\
```

and your settings in:

```
%userprofile%\vimfiles\vimrc
```

For non-Windows users, plugins go into:

```
~/.vim/
```

and settings go into:

```
~/.vim/vimrc
```

If you still use 7.3 or share your config between machines that have 7.3 or 7.4, you can keep the scheme above and add this line to `%userprofile%\_vimrc` (on Windows) or `~/.vim`(on other systems):

```
runtime vimrc
```